# Replace values in dataframe column (regex)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe column with names:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['ROS-053', 'ROS-54', 'ROS-51', 'ROS-051B', 'ROS-051A', 'ROS-52']}) 
df.replace(to_replace=r'[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{2}$', value='new', regex=True)
```

The format needs to be three letters followed by - then three numbers. So ROS-51 should be replaced with ROS-051.. And ROS-051B should be ROS-051. I have tried numerous things but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be highly appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['Names'] = df.Names.replace('^([a-zA-Z]{3})-0?(\d{2})(.*)$', r'\1-0\2', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
     Names
0  ROS-053
1  ROS-054
2  ROS-051
3  ROS-051
4  ROS-051
5  ROS-052
```

Comment: How do you know the three digit number would always start with 0?  Also, your answer doesn't cater to the possibility that the number after the three letters might be just one digit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hence the `?` after `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using regex replacement with a callback:

```
repl = lambda m: m.group(1) + ('00' + m.group(2))[-3:] + m.group(3)
df.str.replace(r'^([A-Z]{3}-)(\d+)(.*)$', repl)
```

Note this answer is flexible and will left pad with zeroes either a single or double digit only to three digits.

Comment: Still a hard no :-)

Comment: I don't work with Pandas often, but I can confirm that the `re.sub` logic is working correctly.

Comment: Not it's not, `ROS-52` gives `ROS-0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['ROS-053', 'ROS-54', 'ROS-51', 'ROS-051B', 'ROS-051A', 'ROS-52']}) 
df['Names'] = df['Names'].str.replace(r'[A-Z]$', '')
df['Names'] = df['Names'].str.split('-').str[0] + '-' + df['Names'].str.split('-').str[1].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(3))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     Names
0  ROS-053
1  ROS-054
2  ROS-051
3  ROS-051
4  ROS-051
5  ROS-052
```